# Convert String to List - c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, data-conversion

I have a list as a single string like - `"['2','4','5','1']"` and length of this is 17 as each char is counted.

Now I want to parse it into list object like - `['2','4','5','1']` whose length will be 4 as the number of elements in a list.

How can I do this in C#?

Can it be done without doing basic string operations? If yes then how?

Comment: `list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<char>>("['2','4','5','1']");`

Comment: Or `var result = str.Split(',','[',']').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();`

Comment: what do you mean by "basic string-operations"? Could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve and in particular what you´ve tried already? We´re not here to do the thinking for you. You have to think yourself. However we can help you, if you have a specific problem or when you´re stuck.

Comment: @SᴇM `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` - don't know if there's a difference in performance, but I'd rather use the option.

Comment: @Fildor Agreed, in that case - `var result = str.Split(new[] { ',','[',']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @Fabio I am really tempted to try and benchmark your solution against the others. I kind of like it and think it fits better the _"without doing basic string operations"_ ... why not make it an answer?

Comment: @SᴇM Splitting the string really worked for me. Its the simplest way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Without basing string operations

Your string value looks like valid JSON array.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<char>>("['2','4','5','1']");

// => ['2','4','5','1']
```

If you need output as integers set output type to be list of integers and JSON serializer will convert it to integers.

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>("['2','4','5','1']");

// => [2, 4, 5, 1]
```

Converting to integers will handle negative values as well ;)

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>("['-2','4','-5','1']");

// => [-2, 4, -5, 1]
```

Comment: Nice idea [@Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio) !

Answer (score 5):

You can try *regular expressions* and *Linq* in order to `Match` all the integers and turn them (`ToList()`) into `List<int>`:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string str = "['2','4','5','1']";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(str, @"\-?[0-9]+")              // \-? for negative numbers
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value)) // int.Parse if you want int, not string
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to `Split` by `,` and then use `Regex` to get only digits:

```
var str = "['2','4','5','1']".Split(new char[] {',' })
    .Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value);
```

Or thanks to [@Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) :

```
var str = Regex.Matches("['2','4','5','1']", @"\d+").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(s=> s.Value);
```

Comment: If you regex match anyway, why split first?